# How to join SQL table to itself, based on the previous record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have the following rows in SQL Server 2016:

[image]

The `ID` is for the patient, and the `LogID` is the unique id of the record, it is an identity column.

How can I get the `FirstVisitDate` of the patients that there dates was changed?

Based on the data in the image, the query should return the row with logID 3 (since the firstVisitDate of the patient has been changed w.r.t to the previous record), and the row with logID 5.

That is:

```
3--2
5--3
```

Which means that the row with logID 3 has been changed from it's previous which is logid=2 and the  record with logID 5 has been changed from it's previous record which is logid=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to get the previous value of the `FirstVisitDate` for each patient and compare that to the current value to see if it has changed:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, LAG(FirstVisitDate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LogID) AS prev_FVD
      FROM visits) v
WHERE FirstVisitDate != prev_FVD
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0db9cfd0f952129d0623b8c20a685629)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you cannot join the table with itself, you can use alias for that with something like the following

```sql
SELECT * 
   FROM 
     PATIENT P JOIN PATIENT P_N ON P.LOGID = PN.LOGID
   WHERE P.FirstVisitDate <> PN.FirstVisitDate 
   ORDER BY P.FirstVisitDate;
```

You have to update the where clause according to your needs.